# "EventSentry" or other for validation before installation

Tags: windows, installer, validation

Our's company product is very big (about 10 Gb) and very complicated.
Main part of it is installed on main computer and some other parts of it are installed on another secondary computers. So before the installation I need to check a lot of things: operating system, disk size, RAM, R/W access, disk drive mapping, registers, etc. My boss recommended me to check if "EventSentry" suits our needs (mostly it is "Computer validation before installation").

So my question is: maybe you know another Windows application suitable for my purpose? Price isn't the issue, license as wide as possible.